# Android: converting string to image and saving to gallery

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, gallery

In my project I need to save a JPG image to android gallery. Unfortunately, Unity tools do not provide such function in-the-box, so I must implement this function myself. As far as I know, I need to make a little plugin to do that and already figured how to make a simple plugin, but I have questions about my specific goal.

So, the main part is: I have texture in Unity, I encode it to JPG format, resulting in a byte array. Then I convert this byte array into a string to be able to pass this string via android bridge into method located in a java class. Everything that's going to happen further is a black box for me.

I know the basic theory: I need to convert the string into an image somehow, specify the folder for the pictures of my app, save the image into this folder, and somehow refresh device memory so the image is visible in the gallery. But the implementation is a big mystery for me. I know it can be done after a few days of digging, but I guess that this can be done in one-two simple methods.

Can anybody give me some hints? Are there any issues between conversion from C# code in Unity into Java code in, for example, Eclipse?